# TYPO3 : Call to undefined method

Tags: typo3, typo3-7.6.x, view-helpers, tx-news, uncaught-exception

Im using TYPO3 version 7.6.32 with News system extension, and from time to time i get an error who then disappears alone without changing anything :

**Error :**

```
Call to undefined method 
GeorgRinger\News\Domain\Model\FileReference::getType()

Error thrown in file /var/www/www.example.com/typo3conf/ext/in_news/Classes/ViewHelpers/IsVideoPlacedViewHelper.php in line 25.
```

I therefore went to see in the famous file `IsVideoPlacedViewHelper.php`.
And this is what I find from line 24 :

```
foreach ($media as $key => $mediaEl) {
    if ($mediaEl->getType() >= 101 && $mediaEl->getType() <= 103 ) {
        return true;
    }
}
```

When I checked the log file, I find this :

```
2019/06/10 08:17:51 [error] 119340#119340: *4509 FastCGI sent in stderr: "PHP message: http://www.example.com/ - Core: Exception handler (WEB): Uncaught TYPO3 Exception: Call to undefined method GeorgRinger\News\Domain\Model\FileReference::getType() | Error thrown in file /var/www/www.example.com/typo3conf/ext/in_news/Classes/ViewHelpers/IsVideoPlacedViewHelper.php in line 25. Requested URL: http://www.example.com/video/" while reading response header from upstream, client: 188.40.199.147, server: in.fo, request: "GET /video/ HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock:", host: "www.example.com"
```

Answer (score 2):

This error occurs because the `IsVideoPlacedViewHelper` does not support the `TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Domain\Model\FileReference` class. (The `news` extension simply extends this domain model.) It expects a `TYPO3\CMS\Core\Resource\FileReference` instead which could be retrieved by `$mediaEL->getOriginalResource()`.

So you should update your `IsVideoPlacedViewHelper` to take this into account:

```php
use TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Domain\Model\FileReference as ExtbaseFileReference;

foreach ($media as $key => $mediaElement) {
    if ($mediaElement instanceof ExtbaseFileReference) {
        $mediaElement = $mediaElement->getOriginalResource();
    }

    $type = $mediaElement->getType();

    if ($type >= 101 && $type <= 103) {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you @Mathias Brodala ! Can you please provide me more information about how to update the `IsVideoPlacedViewHelper`?

Comment: Thank you so much! I will test and keep an eye on the log, since the error does not always appear.